# Giving AWS Api Gateway Permission To Invoke Lambda Function using BOTO3

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, boto3

I am attempting to use BOTO3 to create an Api Gateway method that invokes a lambda function. I have so far been unable to find how to grant the necessary permissions.

Curiously, setting the lambda method name manually through the AWS console sets up permissions automatically. I have been unable to replicate this in code.

This is the code I am using to set up the gateway:

```
# Create a rest api
self.rest_api = self.apigateway.create_rest_api(
    name='AWS_CMS_Operations'
)

# Get the rest api's root id
root_id = self.apigateway.get_resources(
    restApiId=self.rest_api['id']
)['items'][0]['id']

# Create an api resource
api_resource = self.apigateway.create_resource(
    restApiId=self.rest_api['id'],
    parentId=root_id,
    pathPart='AWS_CMS_Manager'
)

# Add a post method to the rest api resource
api_method = self.apigateway.put_method(
    restApiId=self.rest_api['id'],
    resourceId=api_resource['id'],
    httpMethod='POST',
    authorizationType='NONE'
)

# Add an integration method to the api resource
self.apigateway.put_integration(
    restApiId=self.rest_api['id'],
    resourceId=api_resource['id'],
    httpMethod='POST',
    type='AWS',
    integrationHttpMethod='POST',
    uri=self.create_api_invocation_uri()
)

# Set the put method response for the api resource
self.apigateway.put_method_response(
    restApiId=self.rest_api['id'],
    resourceId=api_resource['id'],
    httpMethod='POST',
    statusCode='200',
    responseModels={
        'application/json': 'Empty'
    }
)

# Set the put integration response for the api resource
self.apigateway.put_integration_response(
    restApiId=self.rest_api['id'],
    resourceId=api_resource['id'],
    httpMethod='POST',
    statusCode='200',
    responseTemplates={
        'application/json': ''
    }
)

# Create a deployment of the rest api
self.apigateway.create_deployment(
    restApiId=self.rest_api['id'],
    stageName='prod'
)

# Give the api deployment permission to trigger the lambda function
self.lmda.add_permission(
    FunctionName=self.lmda_function['FunctionName'],
    StatementId='apigateway-production-aws-cms',
    Action='lambda:InvokeFunction',
    Principal='apigateway.amazonaws.com',
    SourceArn=self.create_api_permission_uri(api_resource)
)
```

Everything works fine with the exception of the proper permission being set for the gateway to invoke lambda.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this working in Boto3 using this code:

```
source_arn = f'arn:aws:execute-api:{REGION}:{account_id}:{api_id}/*/*/{api_path}'
lambda_client.add_permission(FunctionName=lambda_function_arn, StatementId=f'invoke_{api_id}', 
        Action='lambda:InvokeFunction', Principal='apigateway.amazonaws.com',
        SourceArn=source_arn)
```

This doesn't use the conventions used in the original question, but there are three things I'd like to point that may help with anyone wrestling with this question:

1. The FunctionName parameter can take the function name, the function's ARN, or the partial ARN according to the [Boto3 Documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.add_permission).
2. The StatementId must be unique in your account. To ensure uniqueness, I appended something to the API ID, since I'll only need one rule per API.
3. The SourceARN is the "execute-api" ARN for your api/staging location.  I haven't seen that ARN used elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

From section 3.6 in this [tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-on-demand-https-example-configure-event-source.html) is a sample CLI command:

```
$ aws lambda add-permissionn \
--function-name <function-name> \
--statement-id apigateway-test-2 \
--action lambda:InvokeFunction \
--principal apigateway.amazonaws.com \
--source-arn "<method-arn">
```

Should be straight forward enough to translate to Boto3.

Comment: This exists in the code in my question. The api gateway is still denied access.

Comment: My bad, didn't see that. Can you also provide the source for self.create_api_permission_uri(api_resource)

Comment: Solved the problem. It had to do with the ARN I was generating. Needed a wildcard in it.

Comment: @ChristopherTreadgold, i have the same issue, i am able to set the permission and i could see in the lambda permission policy, but invoking through API gateway will throw internal server error, any help please