# AWS API Gateway with custom authorizer returns AuthorizerConfigurationException

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless

I have an AWS API Gateway that uses a custom authorizer, and if the request is authorized, it triggers another lambda function. Since yesterday, whenever I call the API, I get an error saying `{ "message": null }` and a 500 Internal Server Error. In the response headers it says `x-amzn-ErrorType →AuthorizerConfigurationException`. I can see in the logs that the authorizer is called and returns a valid policy, and that the other lambda function is not triggered. I have not (knowingly) changed the authorizer. Can anyone give me a hint what might be wrong here? I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38626455/aws-api-gateway-custom-authorizer-authorizerconfigurationexception) question but there the mistake was that the returned policy was wrongly formatted, while I didn't change my authorizer and it worked before.

Comment: I'd recommend running two tests, that will hopefully point out where the error lies. First test a token from the API Gateway (under Authorizers), this will solely test the authorizer. If that works, test the API from API Gateway, this won't invoke the authorizer.

Comment: Thank you, I found the reason for the failure. API Gateway claims that the JSON returned from my authorizer is invalid because it contains a list (that is in the context part, not in the policy. However, according to https://jsonlint.com/ it is valid. If I replace the list with a string, API Gateway accepts the authorizers response. I will ask our contact at Amazon if it is a bug or if this is expected behaviour.

Comment: @Gasp0de the JSON may be valid, but the `context` object is a simple map that only supports scalar strings, so it is an invalid response for that reason. [*"Notice that you cannot set a JSON object or array as a valid value of any key in the context map."*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-lambda-authorizer-output.html)

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks for the info, I did not know that!

Answer (score 0):

The context portion of your policy document can contain only String, Boolean or Numeric values. Arrays and Objects are illegal.

The documentation states:

> The returned values are all stringified. Notice that you cannot set a JSON object or array as a valid value of any key in the context map.

Source:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-lambda-authorizer-output.html