# AWS API Gateway is not being added as a trigger of a AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless

**Situation**:

I have an API hosted in AWS managed via serverless with node.js. Within,
I have three environments in order to have development, testing, and production.

Therefore, each environment has the same lambdas, the same API Gateways, and kind of the same configuration in order to not affect my production environment and test the best while in testing and development (you all know how this goes).

The problem arises when my API gateway has been set as a trigger of my AWS Lambda (which actually works as an authorizer) in testing and production, but it was not set in development. I get the following error headers:

`X-Cache`:`Error from cloudfront`

`x-amzn-ErrorType`: `AuthorizerConfigurationException`

I verified a couple times and even copy pasted the code files for serverless configuration from testing to development to make sure I didn't mistyped, but the configuration is exactly the same.

I'm attaching the images of how it is supposed to look in all three environments, but development is just not. Any help would be appreciated!

````
 handler: path/to/handlerOfAuthorizer
 name: name-Of-Gateway-Authorizer-Lambda
 provisionedConcurrency: 1
 warmup:
   default:
     concurrency: 1
     enabled: true
 concurrencyAutoscaling:
   enabled: true
   maximum: 4
   minimum: 1
   usage: 0.85
   scaleInCooldown: 120
   scaleOutCooldown: 360```
````

[image: API Gateway]

[image: Lambda organization]

Comment: did you manually configured the stack or used the SAM template?

Comment: Hi @Ruben, SAM template was used.

Comment: Share your template

Comment: Just edited :) I added the code used to create the lambda

Comment: would it possible to get the response that you're getting from you authorizer?
[Refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38626455/aws-api-gateway-custom-authorizer-authorizerconfigurationexception)