# Setting PrincipalID for Custom aws lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong with the below API Gateway call.

```
$ curl -i -X POST https://1234567890.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/player/anthology -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Authorization: accesscode" -d "{"fooId":"6", "bucketKey": "fooBucket423"}"

HTTP/2 500
date: Wed, 06 Dec 2023 23:07:39 GMT
content-type: application/json
content-length: 16
x-amzn-requestid: xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx
x-amzn-errortype: AuthorizerConfigurationException
x-amz-apigw-id: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Here is the code for my lambda authorizer. When I make the curl call, the lambda log shows it executes without error.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    logger.info(json.dumps(event))

    api_stage_arn = "%s/*" % "/".join(event["methodArn"].split("/")[0:2])
    effect = "Allow"
    if event['headers']['authorization'] == "accesscode":
        response = {
            "isAuthorized": True,
            "principalId": "myMadeUpPrincipleID123",
            "context": {"anyotherparam": "values"},
            "policyDocument": {
                "Version": "2012-10-17",
                "Statement": [
                    {
                        "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
                        "Effect": effect,
                        "Resource": api_stage_arn,
                    }
                ],
            },
        }
    else:
        response = {
            "isAuthorized": False,
            "context": {
                "anyotherparam": "values"
            }
        }
    logger.info(f"Response: {response}")
    return response
```

Here is my API gateway policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:123456789012:xxxxxxxxx/*/*/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Also is there any documentation that says exactly what fields need to be return from the authorizer?

Comment: May be related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38640351/271415

Comment: I can check but the lambda authorizer executed. would it execute if the api gateway lacked the permission to activate it?

Comment: Agree it would not execute without permission. On the format of the response, see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-lambda-authorizer-output.html).